# how to join two tables using adodb active record in php

Tags: activerecord, adodb

please tell me how to use the below query in adodb active records..

```
SELECT *
FROM students
JOIN class
ON student_class_id = class_id;
```

Thanks..

Comment: Because SQL varies from product to product. I think you will need to add more detail on what is not working to your question.